# MySQL: Why is my trigger never adding 7 days?

Tags: mysql, datetime, triggers

**My table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `files_processed` (
  `filename` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `uploaded_by` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `session_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `datetime_uploaded` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `insert_data` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `generate_positives` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `generate_negatives` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `custom_rules` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `processing_stage` enum('completed','underway','wait','') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'wait',
  `scheduled_processing_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**My trigger:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `setProcessingData` BEFORE INSERT ON `files_processed` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DECLARE vNextDtTime datetime;
   DECLARE vDom varchar(255);
   SET vDom = new.domain;
   SET new.session_id=new.domain;
   
   SELECT max(scheduled_processing_datetime)
   INTO vNextDtTime
   FROM files_processed     
   WHERE domain='@vDom';
   IF (ISNULL(vNextDtTime)) 
   THEN
        SET vNextDtTime := now();
        ELSE
        SET vNextDtTime := DATE_ADD(vNextDtTime, interval 7 day);
        END IF;
   SET new.scheduled_processing_datetime := vNextDtTime;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**My 2 inserts:**

```
INSERT INTO files_processed (filename, uploaded_by, domain)
VALUES ('1.txt', 'hcs.dfc@gmail.com', 'gmail.com');
```

Above is inserting current timestamp which is as expected

```
INSERT INTO files_processed (filename, uploaded_by, domain)
VALUES ('2.txt', 'hcs.dfc@gmail.com', 'gmail.com');
```

Now for this above, I expect the trigger to add 7 days, but it is still treating as current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

vDom is not equal to @vdom

If you put in the variable it works

@ variables are session variables, that can be set and beselected after your insert.

Another think it is better to name a variable _vDom  so that you know even in bigger triggers that is a local variable

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `setProcessingData`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `setProcessingData` BEFORE INSERT ON `files_processed` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DECLARE vNextDtTime datetime;
   DECLARE vDom varchar(255);
   SET vDom = new.domain;
   SET new.session_id=new.domain;

   SELECT max(scheduled_processing_datetime)
   INTO vNextDtTime
   FROM files_processed     
   WHERE domain= vDom;
   IF (ISNULL(vNextDtTime)) 
   THEN
        SET vNextDtTime := now();
        ELSE
        SET vNextDtTime := DATE_ADD(vNextDtTime, interval 7 day);
        END IF;
   SET new.scheduled_processing_datetime := vNextDtTime;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```